# If we rub glass particles with paper , will there be any charge induction in glass particles?

Tags: particle-physics, electrostatics, induction

If we rub glass particles with paper , will there be any charge induction in glass particles ?
I know if you rub with silk they do get charged, but i want to know specifically for glass and paper.

Comment: Why don't you try it for yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most materials rubbed against another (different) material will result in a transfer of charge from one to the other. This is known as the triboelectric effect. The amount of charge transferred can vary considerably and depends on a number of factors including how much energy went into rubbing as well as humidity of the atmosphere.

The [triboelectric series](http://www.trifield.com/content/tribo-electric-series/) can be useful in estimating the amount of charge which will be produced on each material. Materials which are 'far apart' in the series will generally produce more charge when rubbed together, compared to materials which are 'close' to each other in the series.

Both glass and paper have an affinity for positive charge, with glass having a slightly higher (positive) charge affinity of +25 nC/J whereas paper shows +10 nC/J. This means we would expect glass to have a slightly more positive charge (+15 nano-coulombs per joule) when rubbed with paper.

Comment: In this way if we rub glass particles with PVC it will induce more charge into glass. Am I correct ? And based on the series, the charges produced between glass and paper will be very less.

Comment: Thats right, the further apart the two materials are on the series, the more charge will be transferred.

Comment: one more thing will the charge acquired by glass particles will always be positive ( as seen from the series ).

Comment: According to the triboelectric series, the charge on glass rubbed with paper will be only slightly more positive, but since the two materials are so close on the series, it is more sensitive to variations in composition of the glass, coating on the paper as well as chemical treatment, moisture content and air humidity.

Comment: On the other hand, in the case of glass + polyurethane, the polyurethane would have the more positive charge.

Comment: How can I increase the charge in glass particles , will the glass particles get less + charge when PVC is used.

Comment: To increase the amount of charge, the two materials should be far apart on the triboelectric series. Glass and PVC are a good example, or glass and rubber.